# Cross-file references with \includeonly using newclude and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, include

The follow MWE works fine in the sense that I can uncomment `\includeonly{a}` after compiling once, and subsequent compilations have maintain correct references to `B`. This also works when I use `newclude` (uncomment `%1`), or when I load `hyperref` (uncomment `%2`). However, it does not work with both of them loaded.

Am I the first one to notice this apparent incompatibility between `newclude` and the hugely popular `hyperref`? It is not mentioned in the `newclude` manual at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{a.tex}
    \section{A}
    \label{A}
    Ref to B: \ref{B}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{b.tex}
    \section{B}
    \label{B}
    Ref to A: \ref{A}
\end{filecontents}

% uncomment after first compilation!
%0 \includeonly{a}

%1 \usepackage{newclude}

%2 \usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \include{a}
    \include{b}
\end{document}
```

Comment: newclude doesn't seem to have been touched since 1999 and says it was experimental then, do you need it at all?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the one advantage that I use is that is offers `\include*`, which does not issue `\clearpage`s. Very helpful for a long, `section`-based document.

Comment: does it work though? (most implementations of include I have seen that do not use clearpage do not work:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have not noticed anything bad yet, except this issue with `hyperref` and `\includeonly`.